# HTML centre align Tables in Div with button list below

Tags: html, css

I want to centre align a number of tables next to each other at the top in the middle of a div. Underneath these tables I want to have a list of vertical buttons left aligned. I have tried many different techniques but none of which seem to work. Please could someone help?

Current Fiddle Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/Jaron787/gg30jgh5/

CSS

```
.TSS {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10.6px;
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
  /* Safari */
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button1 {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
}

.button1:hover {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="lse" class="display">
  <table id="tblData" class="TSS">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" colspan="4"><b>Table 1</b></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <table id="tblData" class="TSS">
    <tr>
      <td align="center" colspan="4"><b>Table 2</b></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <input type="submit" class="button button1" name="submitButton" value="Button 1">
  <input type="submit" class="button button1" name="submitButton" value="Button 2">
  <input type="submit" class="button button1" name="submitButton" value="Button 3">
  <input type="submit" class="button button1" name="submitButton" value="Button 4">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably just create a wrapper around the tables.

```
<div id="centertbl">
<table id="tblData" class="TSS">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="4"><b>Table 1</b></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="tblData" class="TSS">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="4"><b>Table 2</b></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Then apply the text-align to center.

```
#centertbl { text-align: center;}
```

That will center the tables in middle. Removed the `margin: 0 auto;` from the class `.TSS`.

Change the button css code from `display: inline-block;` to `display: block;`

[jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/gg30jgh5/6/](https://jsfiddle.net/gg30jgh5/6/)

Comment: Works great, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this type of css:

```
please check updeted fiddle link:

some changes in your html structure.table is one div and button is another sepreate div.
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gg30jgh5/9/

Comment: Thanks, but I want the tables next to each other in the centre at the top. Then underneath a list of vertical buttons. Updated the question as it wasn't clear!

Comment: Nice thanks! I just need the buttons vertically aligned below to the left

Comment: Works great, Thanks!

Comment: One more thing: Check out https://jsfiddle.net/Jaron787/gg30jgh5/10/ Ideally i want Table 2 to start at the top along side Table 1 if there are a different number of <tr>'s below. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Set both tables inside a div and set margin-left:50%  for this div
Set all buttons inside a div and set clear:both  for this div.